# Why is empty space a character digit?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char, ascii

I am consuming a long string guaranteed to only be separated by a single white space. I am splitting by whitespace and then counting the substrings that are only digits.

```
var words = longString.split(' ');
var numWordsThatAreNums = 0;

foreach (var word in words) {
   if (word.All(c => c >= '0' && c<= '9')) {
      numWordsThatAreNums++;
   }
}
```

There is a long string that I have verified to have 20 numbers and yet I get 21 for the count. For testing purposes, if the condition above is true, I add the number to a list. At the end, if I print each value from that list on its line

```
Console.WriteLine("Here is" + digit" + "!");
```

the final line is simply blank. Example

```
"Here is1!"
"Here is98!"
"Here is44!"
...
"Here is!"
```

Comment: Because all `Char` values are also 16-bit integers.

Comment: @Dai Correct, though please see the code. I am filtering between character ranges.

Comment: Show us some example input `longString` that reproduces the issue.

Comment: BTW, using `.Split` is kinda inefficient. Your function can be reimplemented using an finite-state-machine loop and be much faster (as there's zero allocations).

Comment: @Dai I updated with examples. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please provide better examples: all of those strings give me a `numWordsThatAreNums` of `0`.   https://imgur.com/a/Fwp547a

Comment: Those are not examples of the strings being consumes, this would be an example of printing out the results

Comment: @Dai Having the example input would make this problem trivial. I would just look at the input myself. What if there was an escape character in the input that I wasn't seeing? Then I come paste the string here and you wouldnt even see the escaped character. You're wasting your own time by going down that road.

Comment: So what is your question then? Because I cannot reproduce the behaviour you're describing at all.

Comment: Could give mock input if your actual data are private.

Comment: @navylover Let's say my mock input is "1 98 44". This wouldnt help anyone solve it because there is no way to tell by my copy+paste if there are some escape characters hidden here that somehow turnout to count as c >= '0' && c <= '9'

Comment: the most obvious explanation is that you have a trailing ' ', and so a zero length string, that will match your `.All` test. You need to set the split flag to say ignore trailing separator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0

Comment: "All" returns `true` when nothing tests false. And when the input is empty, there is nothing to fail the test - so it returns `true`

Answer (score 2):

the most obvious explanation is that you have a trailing ' ', and so a zero length string, that will match your `.All` test.

You need to set the split flag to say ignore empty entries see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0